# I am trying to install Greykite library using Python but its not working? Is it compatible with python? if so, how do I get it?

Tags: python, installation, libraries

python Greykite library

I used the pip install Greykite code but nothing works. I was told that it might be due to the python version I have but I have the python version 3.10.8 which is recently updated

Comment: Looks like it's supported as far as 3.8 as [this issue](https://github.com/linkedin/greykite/issues/76) is still marked as open

Comment: thank you, is there a way to downgrade my current python version to 3.8 and make it work?

Comment: might be worth checking out a tool like pyenv which allows multiple version to be installed